# I was reading my bootstrap.min.js and I can't understanding what this line actually doing here [f = e.attr("data-target");f||(f = e.attr("href")]

Tags: javascript

```
function a(e){..........}
var e = a(this);  
var f = e.attr("data-target");f||(f = e.attr("href"),f=f&&f.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/,""));
```

what this line actually doing here  f||(f = e.attr("href"),
I don't think it is only saying "true" or "false"
if it is shorthand notation then pzl.. explain

Comment: why are you reading library.min.js ?

Comment: Two keys to understand this code: 1) logical operators in js are *short circuiting* and 2) the *comma operator* yields the last value. (That said, people don’t write code like this — that’s the result of *minification*.)

Comment: thanks, I am able to understand short-circuiting

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is some link in data-target attribute's value, If it is not there then It will replace the href attibute's value accoding to the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is a packaged library files, that means all its variables functions are renamed with 1 letter or 2 to optimize the code for compilers

Also alot of instruction are shortened so much, line breacks & spaces are removed

So no human can understand this kind of code without wasting much efforts

If you'd really like to read a library's code, just visit its github repo, or read the non-optimized files , like `bootstrap.js` not the `bootstrap.min.js`